# Convert two for loops to Java Stream?

Tags: java, for-loop, collections, stream, collectors

I have the following nested for loop that I want to convert to use a stream instead as I am currently learning to use streams, how can I do so?

I have added my current attempt below but it is currently incomplete.

```
Part part = getPart();
List<Machines> machines = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> identities = getMachineIdentities();
Set<MachinePart> machineParts = new HashSet<>();

    //create machines
    for (String identity : identities) {
               Machine machine = getMachine(identity);
               machines.add(machine);
           }

    //map to MachineParts
    for (Machine machines : machines) {
               MachinePart machinePart = MachinePartCreator.new(machines, part);
               machineParts.add(machinePart);
           }
```

**Stream attempt:**

```
Set<MachinePart > machineParts = identities.stream()
    .map(identity-> ??? ).collectors.collect(Collectors.toSet()));
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your first loop creates the input for the second loop. This can be achieved with two `map()` calls:

```
Set<MachinePart> machineParts =
    identities.stream()
              .map(id -> getMachine(id))
              .map(m -> MachinePartCreator.new(m, part))
              .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Or even one:

```
Set<MachinePart> machineParts =
    identities.stream()
              .map(id -> MachinePartCreator.new(getMachine(id),part))
              .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Of course, you can also write the original code with a single for loop and skip the intermediate `List<Machines> machines`.

Comment: thanks, what is happening in the two .map() lines? Just wondering for my own knowledge going forward.

Comment: @java12399900 the first `map` call transforms a `Stream<String>` to a `Stream<Machine>` and the second `map` call transforms a `Stream<Machine>` to a `Stream<MachinePart>`.

Comment: thanks, what are the advantages of using stream here, I feel that loops are easier to debug and read?

Comment: @java12399900 I don't think that such basic code needs much debugging. And once you get used to Streams, they might become easier to read.

Comment: what are the advantages though in general?

Comment: @java12399900 well, stream pipelines can make your code more concise (shorter and clearer) once you get used to it.